# Why can we use only four operators (+,-,++,--) in pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, operators

Why can we use only four operators (`+`, `-`, `++`, `--`) in pointer arithmetic? Does it have any relation with inbuilt hardware since it is dealing with addresses?

Since an array uses relative addressing, in that we increment the address to perform that operation, I think this might be one of the reasons for using those 4 operators alone.

Comment: What other operators do you think make sense?

Comment: @John3136: To be fair, something like `ptr % 8` might actually be useful.

Comment: @KeithThompson: If you know that works, `int *p; ... uintptr_t boff = ((uintptr_t)p % 8);`. `p % 8` might not make much sense on all architectures for all divisors (e.g with segment:offset porters like x86-16bit).

Comment: what would the operators do?  if you take a pointer and multiply or divide or what else do, what would expected as result?

Comment: @Olaf: I've worked on systems where that would fail badly. (Cray vector machines. A hardware address is 64 bits, pointing to a 64-bit word. Byte addresses where synthesized by the compiler by storing an offset in the upper 3 bits. Conversions between pointers and integers just copied the bits.) If `ptr % integer` were defined by the language (and there are excellent reasons why it isn't), then the compiler could generate whatever code is needed to get the right answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That's why I wrote "If you know that works". Sometimes one has to rely on implementation details. But, of course, that should be burried deply in the OS/driver and in as few functions as possible.

Comment: (I'd post this as an answer if I could.) Those are the only supported arithmetic operators for pointers simply because they're the only ones that make sense. Adding, multiplying, or dividing two pointers would not yield a meaningful result. Computing something like `ptr % 8` could make sense, but the restrictions that would have to be imposed would be too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can we use only four operators (+, -, ++, --) in pointer arithmetic?

Because the language was built that way. The most common operation is iteration, which is probably why those operators are allowed.

As for rationales behind why the C language was designed this way, there's not much to be found. I checked the C99 rationale regarding pointer arithmetic, but it is mostly concerned about the result of pointer arithmetic overflowing and does not mention why/when pointer arithmetic makes sense.

> Does it have any relation with inbuilt hardware since it is dealing with addresses?

No, it has nothing to do with that. Addresses are just numbers. You can always cast any pointer to `uintptr_t` and then use it as any other integer.

Comment: Addresses are not just numbers. They might be implemented that way in hardware, but a C pointer value is a pointer value; pointers are not arithmetic types. As for the rationale, it seems clear enough to me; those are the only operations that make sense.

Comment: For `uintptr_t`, only casting from a pointer and back **to the same type** is guaranteed. Also it is guaranteed that it is an (unsigned) integer type, so it can also store an integer value. But if you change the stored pointer value and convert that back, nothing is defined by the standard. It is - strictly speaking - undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KeithThompson There are lots of operators that would make sense to use on addresses. `& | ~` to manipulate or mask bits. `%` to check if a pointer is aligned. Etc. But because of the type system requires those operators to have integer operands, pointer type cannot be used. The only thing they achieved with this restriction is to make C less useful.

Comment: @KeithThompson Similarly, any assumption that pointers are not number makes C less useful, because 99.9% of all existing computers in the real world, pointers are numbers. Unfortunately the C standard is not in sync with reality, because the C standard strives to give unorthodox, obsolete-since-ages or completely fictional computers the same status as mainstream production, two's complement computers where addresses are numbers from 0 and upwards.

Comment: @Olaf: More than that, conversion to and from `uintptr_t` is defined only for `void*`.

Comment: @Lundin: If you want to treat pointers as integers, you can convert them to `uintptr_t` and back again. The results aren't guaranteed to be portable, but that's fine if you don't care about that. Requiring pointers to act like integers would have made C implementations for Cray vector machines much more difficult; likewise for systems with segmented addresses, like old-style x86. I disagree with your point, BTW, (Not many people say that C's problem is that it's too type-safe.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Strictly speaking you are right. But then you also can cast any pointer to a `void *` and back. That would just require another two casts (I didn't say how many casts it requires ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You can use any operator, as long as the result will be int. For example:

```
int A[10], i=5;
int *p;
p = A + (i/2);
```

Comment: `(1/2)` is simply `0`. You haven't shown pointer division, you've simply added `0` to a pointer.

Comment: @Keith-Thompson, 1/2?? I wrote `i/2`, with `i` initialized to 5, giving 2, hence `&A[2]`.

Comment: My mistake, I misread it. But my point stands. `(i/2)` is still just an integer expression, and all you've done is add an integer to a pointer -- and the result is not an `int`, which contradicts your first sentence. The question isn't about arithmetic operations on integers, it's about arithmetic operations on pointers.

Answer (score -2):

Simple because C was designed that way.

`+,-` can be simply used to add or subtract two pointers respectively (value at address only). While on the other hand increment and decrement operators i.e ++ and -- can be used to increment or decrement the pointer.Remember the data type of pointer plays an important role in these two(++,--) operators.

For example if you define an pointer of type *int then ++ will increment the memory address by 2 (since the size of int in most compilers is 2 ) and so same is with the -- operator as it will decrease it by a 2.

Comment: `+` cannot be used to add two pointers. You can add a pointer to an integer, or an integer to a pointer. Adding two pointers doesn't make sense. Also, subtracting two pointers yields an integer, not a pointer. And the type of the pointer also affects the behavior of `+` and `-`.

Comment: I want to say that pointer variable can be used to add values at that address... Like *p + *q can be added and it means that values at address p and q can be added by +

Comment: That's not relevant to the question. `*p + *q` is not pointer addition; it's simply integer addition (assuming `p` and `q` are pointers to integers); similarly, `*p / *q` is not pointer division.

Comment: In the queation it was asked why + can be used and am only saying that same thing that using + value at address can be added